# Global Class not changing my value

Tags: c#, winforms, static-members

I created a global class that holds most of the information i need through out my program, the issue is that when i update the balance and i go back to check the balance it remains the same, although when i step trough the code, it shows that i am modifying it.. here is my global class

```
public class Global
{

    public static decimal AccountBalance
    {
        get { return _AccountBalance; }
        set { _AccountBalance = value; }
    }
```

So when I am updating an account I do

```
Global.AccountBalance  = acct.AccountBalace;
```

But then I have a message that displays the amount later on if the person wants to see the balance like this

```
lblBalance.Text = "Your Balance : " + Global.AccountBalance.ToString("C", ctr);
```

But that line is still returning the old balance... Any help with letting me know what i may have done wrong would be much apprecioated.

Comment: Not sure but i think issues with Threads and hence the old value getting reflected, try decorating the member with `[ThreadStatic]` attribute

Comment: You can insert a breakpoint inside the setter of the `AccountBalance` and monitor changes to the property. Put your cursor inside `set { _AccountBalance = value; }` and press `F9` (Visual Studio). Then run your program and see who changes the value.

Comment: I did that.. all the way up to that point.. the value of the object is correct and the value of the global value is too.. is just that when i go back to the screen where i have a label displaying the value still shows the same number..

Comment: Are you sure the label is not getting updated from anywhere else? there seems nothing wrong the above code..

Comment: no i did a search.. and have stepped through,, i dont understand either why the label.. perhaps is not refreshing..

Comment: If you *are* going to have a singleton, either do it completely one way or the other - either have entirely instance (non-static) members (except `Instance`) and access everything via `Global.Instance`, or make everything `static` and prevent the `Global` object from being constructed. The current half-and-half implementation hurts my head.

Comment: I agree with @Damien. I don't see how this code can handle more than one customer. [ThreadStatic] will not help in this case.

Comment: Yeah i had it like that before too, and it did not work (all the way using intance without the static).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what attracts my attention is:  `public override bool AdjustAccountBalance`.
I'd suggest that `public override` means that this code could called from anywhere.
I such cases I usually follow dirty-but-reliable approach:

- Add logging(to local file `C:\log.txt`, I warn that it's dirty way :)) of all calls(with timestamp and stacktrace) of property `Global.AccountBalance` setter and `AdjustAccountBalance` method;
- Reproduce the problem;
- Dig into log and investigate all calls to mentioned methods; Find "aha-there-it-is"-code;
- ???
- Profit

So, your code will look similary to this:
Helper class:

```
internal static class LogHelper
{
    public void LogCall(string method, string details, StackFrame[] stackTrace)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(DateTie.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " method + "{" + details + "}");
        foreach (StackFrame stackFrame in stackTrace)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(stackFrame.GetMethod().Name);
        }

        File.AppendText("C:\\log.txt", sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

AdjustAccountBalance method(amended fragment):

```
public override bool AdjustAccountBalance(Account acct, decimal amount, string transType)   
{
.. lots of your code posted in question..
 case "D":
 LogHelper.LogCall("AdjustAccountBalance","D-case",new StackTrace().GetFrames())
 acct.AccountBalace += amount;                           
 Global.AccountBalance  = acct.AccountBalace;                           
 break;                       
 case "W":                           
 if (acct.AccountBalace >= amount)                           
 {
LogHelper.LogCall("AdjustAccountBalance","W-case",new StackTrace().GetFrames())
 acct.AccountBalace -= amount;                               
 Global.AccountBalance = acct.AccountBalace;       

 }                       
 break;   
.. lots of your code posted in question..

 }
```

`AccountBalance` property of `Global` class:

```
public static decimal AccountBalance
 {            
  get { return _AccountBalance; }
  set {
   LogHelper.LogCall("set_AccountBalance","value is " + value,new StackTrace().GetFrames())
  _AccountBalance = value; 
  }        
  }
```

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
Global.AccountBalance  = acct.AccountBalace;
```

What type is 'acct? If it is of type Global, then that line will do nothing, since you are assigning the static _AccountBalance to itself.

Comment: acct is of type   Account acct = new Account();

Comment: I updated and added the functione above.. The account being passed as a parameter is a Account acct = new Account(); there  is no passing of the global stuff among the methods.. it is only used to set and store stuff there.

Comment: @user710502 Did you try as per my comment ? coz it seemed like a thread safety issue